# How to avoid translation tools from messing up HTML tags?

Tags: html, translation

I always use Google translate and paste back the the results in Vim. But for some reason Google translate also screws up the HTML tags around the content I want to translate. Is there a solution for this?

For instance, the double quotes are translated to Chinese-cased double quotes:

```
'pictures_h2'=>“我們課程和活動的照片
```

Strong and li tags are translated too (well I kinda expected that).

P S :　IS there any translator which respect HTML tags? or translation plugin for Vim?

Answer (score 1):

http://translate.google.com/support/?hl=en

General information for webmasters
Preventing translation of your webpages

If you don't mind your web page being translated by Google Translate, except for a particular section (like an email address, for example), just add class=notranslate to any HTML element to prevent that element from being translated. For example: Email us at  sales at example dot com